# AEM Reverse Replication with two publisher

Tags: java, aem

I Have two Publisher and one Author Server.
I use reverse Replication for Usergenerated Content, for modified Content.
So I have also a Forward Replication (Selfmade, because AEM havent).

The Problem is, that the Replication between the Publisher going in an endless loop. So they replicate like playing ping pong.

What can I do about the ping pong play of the publishers?

I'm Using CQ 6.1, Java 1.7

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by a self-made forward replication agent - is this custom code or simply a configured default replication agent?

Comment: How is your author-to-publish replication agent configured in regards to its triggers? Do you have the "On Receive" or "On Modification" triggers enabled?

Comment: Its a standard self mad forward repliation for User Generated Content, because AEM  has no Workflow for that (I dont know why). I have no Triggers checked on true.

Comment: The Forward replication is neede because the reverse replication is going just from publish to author, if I want to replicate to the other publisher i have to use a forward replicator, or is that wrong?

Comment: Please don't include code as a screenshot. [Edit] your question and include your code *as text*.

Comment: i have changed my content, and deleted the code. Can you delete your downvote please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a Solution.

1. Set Replication Options --> watch printscreen
2. Adapt WorkflowSession in Session class to replicate
3. Close Sessionafter replication
4. Never close Workflow Session
5. Clean outbox on publishers in crx (/var/replication/outbox) [every time, if something fails]
6. Create Launcher for Reverse replication Create & Modified (with condition: cq:distribute!=)
7. Create Launcher for Forward replication Create & Modified (code example)

> Because I have more than one Forward Replicator, I made an Abstract
>   Class. If you don't use it, put all in one class
>
> Attention: with ReplicationOption setSynchronous(true), the
>   replication was fine to replicate from publisher to publisher. But
>   because I have an administration page on author, I have to unncomment
>   this attribute. Because the changes on Auhtor were not replicated to
>   the publishe

```
@Component(immediate = true)
@Service(value = WorkflowProcess.class)
public class ReplicateUsergeneratedContentToPublishWorkflow extends     AbstractAuthorToPublishWorkflow implements WorkflowProcess{
// OSGI properties
@Property(value = "This workflow replicate usergenerated content from author to publisher")
static final String DESCRIPTION = Constants.SERVICE_DESCRIPTION;

@Property(value = "Titel")
static final String VENDOR = Constants.SERVICE_VENDOR;

@Property(value = "Replicate the usergenerated content from one publisher via author to the ohter publisher")
static final String LABEL = "process.label";

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReplicateUsergeneratedContentToPublishWorkflow.class);

@Reference
private ResourceResolverFactory resolverFactory;

@Reference
protected Replicator replicator;

@Reference
private SlingRepository repository;

@Reference
SlingSettingsService slingSettingsService;
@Override
public void execute(WorkItem workItem, WorkflowSession workflowSession, MetaDataMap metaDataMap) throws WorkflowException {
    Session session = null;
    SimpleCredentials administrator = new SimpleCredentials("username", "password".toCharArray());
    try {
        java.util.Set<String> runModes = slingSettingsService.getRunModes();
        session = repository.login(administrator);
        //the replication need to check the payload
        String payload = workItem.getWorkflowData().getPayload().toString();
        Node node = null;
        if (session.itemExists(payload)) {
            node = (Node) session.getItem(payload);
        }

        activateNode(node, workflowSession, replicator);
        //save all changes
        session.save();
    } catch (PathNotFoundException e) {
        LOGGER.error("path not found", e);
        workflowSession.terminateWorkflow(null);
    } catch (ReplicationException e) {
        LOGGER.error("error replicating content node", e);
        workflowSession.terminateWorkflow(null);
    } catch (RepositoryException e) {
        LOGGER.error("error reading path to content node", e);
        workflowSession.terminateWorkflow(null);
    }finally{
        if(session != null){
            session.logout();
        }
    }
}
}


public abstract class AbstractAuthorToPublishWorkflow implements WorkflowProcess {

protected void activateNode(Node node, WorkflowSession workflowSession, Replicator replicator) throws RepositoryException, ReplicationException {
    ReplicationOptions replicationOptions = new ReplicationOptions();
    replicationOptions.setSuppressStatusUpdate(true);
    replicationOptions.setSuppressVersions(true);
    //replicationOptions.setSynchronous(true);

    //the property cq:distribute is settet if the node should be replicated from publisher to author (set it in your own code)
    if (node != null) {
        node.setProperty("cq:distribute", (Value) null);

        //important use WorkflowSession and adapt it to Session class, replication is going to an endless loop, if you doing it without WorkflowSession
        replicator.replicate(workflowSession.adaptTo(Session.class), ReplicationActionType.ACTIVATE, node.getPath(), replicationOptions);
    }
}
}
```

Special for User And Group forward Replication, don't interfere the deactivate action from useradmin on author

```
            //Important that you don't interfer the Deactivate Action from useradmin
        //do nothing if the action is deactivate!
        if( !userNode.getProperty("cq:lastReplicationAction").getString().equals("Deactivate")) {
            activateNode(userNode, workflowSession, replicator);
            //save all changes
            session.save();
        }
```

And for the the codepart were I modifie a node in author, I add this

```
    //quickfix
    //FrameworkUtil.getBundle(NodeManageDAO.class).getBundleContext()
    BundleContext bundleContext = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(PhotoNodeManagerDAO.class).getBundleContext();
    ServiceReference serviceReference = bundleContext.getServiceReference(SlingSettingsService.class.getName( ));
    SlingSettingsService slingSettingsService = (SlingSettingsService)bundleContext.getService(serviceReference);
    Set<String> runmode= slingSettingsService.getRunModes();

    //just in author mode
    if(runmode.contains("author")) {
        //attention replication from author is not working without nullable / delete the cq:distribute property
        node.setProperty("cq:distribute", (Value)null);
    }
```

> If you have a updated your workflow model, than you have to restart the worklflow and clean the failures and the cadaverous from old replication configs. Clean on author and on each publisher seperated, go to crx under /etc/workflow/launcher/config.

For the reverse replicator on publisher, set also the condition: cq:distribute!=

and on each part in the code where you change the nodes, add the following three properties

```
node.setProperty("cq:distribute", ValueFactoryImpl.getInstance().createValue("true"));
node.setProperty("cq:lastModifiedBy", ValueFactoryImpl.getInstance().createValue(session.getUserID()));
node.setProperty("cq:lastModified", ValueFactoryImpl.getInstance().createValue(Calendar.getInstance()));
session.save();
```

Sample of the Launchers [authorserver]/etc/workflow.html --> launchers

[image]

Comment: I think in a former project we "just" added a property to check if data was already replicated. But that meant to create custom workflows as well ... this is just a comment.

Comment: I've made a correction. Dont close workflow session!!